# Android compose onClick being called before click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having issues whit the onClick on Jetpack compose, it performs the click as soon as I run the app and after returning to this activity the button stops working. Any insights?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            linkButton("Go to text views", goTo(context, TextViewActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun linkButton(msg: String, link: Unit) {
    Button(onClick = {
        link
    }) {
        Text(msg)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMessageCard() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    linkButton(
        msg = "Sample",
        link = goTo(context, TextViewActivity::class.java)
    )
}

private fun goTo(context: Context, clazz: Class<*>) {
    context.startActivity(Intent(context, clazz))
}
```

Comment: Your parameter type in `linkButton` is wrong. You are getting a `Unit` but you need a `() -> Unit`. The way you have written it causes the `goto` to be called immediately in `setContent`. In other words, you are calling the function instead of passing it.

Comment: @momt99 so if I undestand you correctly I should change the method parameter to "fun linkButton(msg: String, link: () -> Unit)" and then call it this way? linkButton("Go to text views") { goTo(context, TextViewActivity::class.java) }

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: I've been testing that, but the goTo Method never gets called

Comment: Have you updated your `linkButton` method? You should call the parameter in `onClick` like `link()`.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks mate publish your answer if you want so I can accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238396/discussion-between-momt99-and-jose-gonzalez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually calling the method at the moment you are composing the `linkButton`, not passing it as a callback to be called on click. And on click, it is just returning a `Unit` which causes the unexpected behavior.

To fix that, you should change the parameter type in your composable function to `() -> Unit`, which represents a function type.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            linkButton("Go to text views") {
                goTo(context, TextViewActivity::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LinkButton(msg: String, link: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = {
        link()
    }) {
        Text(msg)
    }
}
```